# Google Analytics shows avg. session, sometimes 00:00:00 sometimes not 0

Tags: android, session, google-analytics, duration

I integrated google anaylitics into my android game 5 days ago and published. Yesterday, I noticed that many sessions'(almost half of all sessions) duration is 00:00:00. Rest of sessions seems normal, no problem. My game has just 1 activity, it uses swipe tabs.

I found some solutions from websites, they say that "increase bounce rate". But there is no bounce rate for android applications as you know. This solutions is for website analysis. I couldn't solve any solution for android application that has just 1 activity.

What is the main reason? How to solve?

For 5 days:

[image]

For today:

[image]

Comment: This game can be played off-line.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple shots in the dark - since you didn't include code. Check these and if it isn't any of them, edit your post with your code please:

1) Session control field must be changed after an event is sent - something other than "start" or "end"

2) make sure that your non-interactive flag isn't set (&ni=1) though I would expect you to have all 0s if that was the case.

3) ensure that you aren't calling startNewSession repeatedly, only once.

4) turn on verbose logging and see if the answer jumps out at you.

more info on v4 sessions -> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/sessions